# Передать массив данных по tcp в python

Tags: python, сокет, tcp

Как вместо (b'Hello') передать массив a = [0,0,0,127]

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 6667))  # The address of the TCP server listening
s.send(b'Hello')
s.close()
```

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе в комментарии написали как.

Comment: Преобразуйте массив в json и отправьте

Comment: Это называется сериализация объектов. https://pep8.ru/doc/dive-into-python-3/15.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать pickle

```
s.send(pickle.dumps([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: Лучше уж json, т.к. `pickle` может быть небезопасен, т.к. в него можно вписать код, который выполнится при десериализации, хоть это и параноидально, но как аргумент сгодится :)